# How can i disable a button from closing a material dialog when clicking it?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a angular material dialog that contains a button that i would like it to execute something and display the result on the dialog without closing it.

tried this but it didn't work : `[mat-dialog-close]="false"`

```
<mat-dialog-actions align="center">
  <button class="mat-raised-button mat-primary" mat-dialog-close>back </button>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="lunchScraper()" [mat-dialog-close]="false">lunch scraping</button>
  <button mat-button type="submit" class="mat-raised-button mat-accent" (click)="onSubmit()">add</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

How do I disable the button from closing the dialog ?

Comment: Theoretically you should be able to just remove the [matDialogClose] attribute from the lunchScraper button. In practice, as I'm currently finding out, this has no effect.. i see in the source html that the matdialogclose attribute is still there /&%/&!%"!!! I've tried deleting the cache but its resistant :-(

Comment: Did you manage to find out how ? i tried to search over google but it seems like no solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove this part

```
this.dialogRef.close();
```

in the controller of appear there

Answer (score 0):

Okay; `mat-dialog-close` is an Angular Directive which expect data to pass to the host component.

So; `[mat-dialog-close]="false"` will pass `false` value as dialog data to the component which launched this dialog.

You can close dialog in 2 ways:

1. Using `mat-dialog-close`: this is the easiest way but you cannot prevent it from close dialog unless you disabled the button itself.
2. Using `dialogRef` in ts file: by adding a function that call `close()` function of `dialogRef` variable; and call your function on click button.

I made you [this dialog demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ygvfjp) which has a dialog with 2 buttons; one of them uses `mat-dialog-close` and another with `close` function.

I hope that will help you to get my point.

Comment: it didn't work for me. i already tried using [mat-dialog-close]="false" but the button still closes the dialog. in fact any button closes the dialog ( exp : <button> anything </button> ).

Comment: You should see the example up.  Mat-dialog-close accept the result to be sent to host component; not to enable or disable it.

Comment: BTW; try to use a component function instead of this directive; it’s also in the example up.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question, I believe the idea is for a submit button not to close the dialog but instead to close the dialog manually.
For this, follow these steps:

1. On the submit button, remove the `[mat-dialog-close]="false"` code entirely.
2. To be able to close the dialog, use a function and then in the function make use of the `MatDialogRef`, i.e:

> ```
> constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditComponent>) {};
>
> this.dialogRef.close('Pizza!');
> ```

"pizza" is the data that will be sent back on dialog close